# Exited MongoDB uncleanly and now unsure how to get it running again

Tags: mongodb

I was filling up a MongoDB collection faster than I realized and basically ran out of disk space, but I think I exited it uncleanly. I tried reinstalling MongoDB using Homebrew, but I'm getting the following mess of errors and am not sure how to fix things.

```
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12791 port=27017 

dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=Evan-Zamirs-MacBook-Air.local
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] 
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] git version: f5e83eae9cfbec7fb7a071321928f00d1b0c5207
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-1.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb" }
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten]  test.system.namespaces Assertion failure isOk() src/mongo/db/pdfile.h 360
0x10037637b 0x1000b0196 0x10029eb1b 0x1002a3838 0x10013056b 0x10056c80b 0x1005708f7 0x100570d75 0x1000828cb 0x100084f13 0x1006464c9 0x1006494d6 0x10064aec9 0x100175487 0x1001ac2df 0x10063efbf 0x100004ca6 0x100005815 0x10000608d 0x10000d534 
 0   mongod                              0x000000010037637b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongod                              0x00000001000b0196 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 310
 2   mongod                              0x000000010029eb1b _ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr7findAllEPKcRKNS_7DiskLocE + 1659
 3   mongod                              0x00000001002a3838 _ZN5mongo13findTableScanEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_7DiskLocE + 312
 4   mongod                              0x000000010013056b _ZNK5mongo9QueryPlan9newCursorERKNS_7DiskLocE + 603
 5   mongod                              0x000000010056c80b _ZN5mongo15CursorGenerator16singlePlanCursorEv + 443
 6   mongod                              0x00000001005708f7 _ZN5mongo15CursorGenerator8generateEv + 199
 7   mongod                              0x0000000100570d75 _ZN5mongo25NamespaceDetailsTransient9getCursorEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES5_RKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyEPbRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_11ParsedQueryEEEbPNS_16QueryPlanSummaryE + 69
 8   mongod                              0x00000001000828cb _ZN5mongo23queryWithQueryOptimizerEiRKSsRKNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpES4_S4_RKN5boost10shared_ptrINS_11ParsedQueryEEES4_RKNS_17ShardChunkVersionERNS7_10scoped_ptrINS_25PageFaultRetryableSectionEEERNSG_INS_19NoPageFaultsAllowedEEERNS_7MessageE + 363
 9   mongod                              0x0000000100084f13 _ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_ + 3187
 10  mongod                              0x00000001006464c9 _ZN5mongoL13receivedQueryERNS_6ClientERNS_10DbResponseERNS_7MessageE + 393
 11  mongod                              0x00000001006494d6 _ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE + 950
 12  mongod                              0x000000010064aec9 _ZN5mongo14DBDirectClient4callERNS_7MessageES2_bPSs + 121
 13  mongod                              0x0000000100175487 _ZN5mongo14DBClientCursor4initEv + 167
 14  mongod                              0x00000001001ac2df _ZN5mongo12DBClientBase5queryERKSsNS_5QueryEiiPKNS_7BSONObjEii + 191
 15  mongod                              0x000000010063efbf _ZN5mongo14DBDirectClient5queryERKSsNS_5QueryEiiPKNS_7BSONObjEii + 79
 16  mongod                              0x0000000100004ca6 _ZN5mongo19clearTmpCollectionsEv + 710
 17  mongod                              0x0000000100005815 _ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi + 1093
 18  mongod                              0x000000010000608d _ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi + 29
 19  mongod                              0x000000010000d534 _ZL11mongoDbMainiPPc + 29348
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] assertion 0 assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:360 ns:test.system.namespaces query:{ options.temp: { $in: [ true, 1 ] } }
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] problem detected during query over test.system.namespaces : { $err: "assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:360" }
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten]  tutorial.system.namespaces Assertion failure isOk() src/mongo/db/pdfile.h 360
0x10037637b 0x1000b0196 0x10029eb1b 0x1002a3838 0x10013056b 0x10056c80b 0x1005708f7 0x100570d75 0x1000828cb 0x100084f13 0x1006464c9 0x1006494d6 0x10064aec9 0x100175487 0x1001ac2df 0x10063efbf 0x100004ca6 0x100005815 0x10000608d 0x10000d534 
0x10037637b 0x1000b0196 0x10029eb1b 0x1002a3838 0x10013056b 0x10056c80b 0x1005708f7 

0x100570d75 0x1000828cb 0x100084f13 0x1006464c9 0x1006494d6 0x10064aec9 0x100175487 0x1001ac2df 0x10063efbf 0x100004ca6 0x100005815 0x10000608d 0x10000d534 
 0   mongod                              0x000000010037637b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongod                              0x00000001000b0196 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 310
 2   mongod                              0x000000010029eb1b _ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr7findAllEPKcRKNS_7DiskLocE + 1659
 3   mongod                              0x00000001002a3838 _ZN5mongo13findTableScanEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjERKNS_7DiskLocE + 312
 4   mongod                              0x000000010013056b _ZNK5mongo9QueryPlan9newCursorERKNS_7DiskLocE + 603
 5   mongod                              0x000000010056c80b _ZN5mongo15CursorGenerator16singlePlanCursorEv + 443
 6   mongod                              0x00000001005708f7 _ZN5mongo15CursorGenerator8generateEv + 199
 7   mongod                              0x0000000100570d75 _ZN5mongo25NamespaceDetailsTransient9getCursorEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES5_RKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyEPbRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_11ParsedQueryEEEbPNS_16QueryPlanSummaryE + 69
 8   mongod                              0x00000001000828cb _ZN5mongo23queryWithQueryOptimizerEiRKSsRKNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpES4_S4_RKN5boost10shared_ptrINS_11ParsedQueryEEES4_RKNS_17ShardChunkVersionERNS7_10scoped_ptrINS_25PageFaultRetryableSectionEEERNSG_INS_19NoPageFaultsAllowedEEERNS_7MessageE + 363
 9   mongod                              0x0000000100084f13 _ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_ + 3187
 10  mongod                              0x00000001006464c9 _ZN5mongoL13receivedQueryERNS_6ClientERNS_10DbResponseERNS_7MessageE + 393
 11  mongod                              0x00000001006494d6 _ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE + 950
 12  mongod                              0x000000010064aec9 _ZN5mongo14DBDirectClient4callERNS_7MessageES2_bPSs + 121
 13  mongod                              0x0000000100175487 _ZN5mongo14DBClientCursor4initEv + 167
 14  mongod                              0x00000001001ac2df _ZN5mongo12DBClientBase5queryERKSsNS_5QueryEiiPKNS_7BSONObjEii + 191
 15  mongod                              0x000000010063efbf _ZN5mongo14DBDirectClient5queryERKSsNS_5QueryEiiPKNS_7BSONObjEii + 79
 16  mongod                              0x0000000100004ca6 _ZN5mongo19clearTmpCollectionsEv + 710
 17  mongod                              0x0000000100005815 _ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi + 1093
 18  mongod                              0x000000010000608d _ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi + 29
 19  mongod                              0x000000010000d534 _ZL11mongoDbMainiPPc + 29348
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] assertion 0 assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:360 ns:tutorial.system.namespaces query:{ options.temp: { $in: [ true, 1 ] } }
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] problem detected during query over tutorial.system.namespaces : { $err: "assertion src/mongo/db/pdfile.h:360" }
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] Dropping old temporary collection: 
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10011 no collection name, terminating
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 dbexit: 
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Fri Oct 19 20:40:20 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: I had this once, it is database corruption...

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to reinstall mongoDB.You can repair it by following the steps given by Stennie

**OR**

You can delete data/db or wherever your data directory resides and create new folder again with the same name data/db.
After that goto the directory where data folder resides and start mongo server with mongod command.

But you will lost your data but its a fast way to restart.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have some database corruption and need to run [`repair`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair) on your databases.  The repair process essentially rebuilds a database and skips over suspect data.  It will temporarily need enough space for an extra copy of the database (or at least the "good" data that can be copied) so this may not be an option if you are still low on disk space.

You can a repair on all databases with:

```
`mongod --repair`
```

If you have another drive mounted with more space, you can pass a `--repairpath` argument so the repair uses a different path for temproary files created during the repair.

If `mongod` were not crashing on startup, you would also have the option of running repair on individual databases from within the `mongo` shell by using a db and invoking:

> db.repairDatabase()

Reinstalling MongoDB as you have done will not fix any problems in the data files.  If you aren't concerned about the data (for example, the log excerpt above references `test` and `tutorial`) .. you could also delete the data directory and start fresh.  It looks like your data directory would be: `/usr/local/var/mongodb`.

Comment: while running db.repairDatabase() i got the error  {
 "errmsg" : "exception: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp:109",
 "code" : 0,
 "ok" : 0
}
Please suggest any solution

Comment: @SapnaBhayal The answer you're commenting on is from 2012 -- a lot has changed since then including the default storage engine. Please post a new question with details of your environment including MongoDB server version, deployment type (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster) and the steps leading up to needing a repair. This discussion would also be more on-topic for [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongodb).